# Associate a URL with a resource within my application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I visit `http://my-application.com/posts/1` in my browser, Rails knows I'm looking for the `Post` with `id = 1`. How can I get my application to do this internally? I.e., I'd like a function (call it `associate_with_resource`) that takes a string containing a URL as its input and outputs the associated resource. For example:

```
>> associate_with_resource('http://my-application.com/posts/1')
=> #<Post id: 1, ... >
```

(I'd like to be able to use `associate_with_resource` throughout my application though -- not only in the console)

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm looking for the `ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path` method

Answer (score 1):

You are right about `ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path` and I would do it like this:

create a file `lib/associate_with_resource.rb`

```
module AssociateWithResource
  def associate_with_resource(path)
    url_hash = ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path path
    url_hash[:controller].classify.constantize.find(url_hash[:id])
  end
end

class ActionController::Base
  include AssociateWithResource
  helper_method :associate_with_resource
end

class ActiveRecord::Base
  include AssociateWithResource
end
```

Now you can call the `associate_with_resource(path)` from almost everywhere to get the resource belonging to a given path

Answer (score 0):

> When I visit http://my-application.com/posts/1 in my browser, Rails knows I'm looking for the Post with id = 1.

This is not correct.

In Rails 3, when you put this into `routes.rb`:

```
resources :posts
```

Then Rails will know that you have a controller named `PostsController` in the file `app/controllers/posts_controller.rb`. Rails will also know that in your `PostsController` class, you have seven methods that are intended to be action methods: `index`, `new`, `create`, `show`, `edit`, `update`, `delete`.

What you do in these action methods is entirely up to you. You may wish to retrieve and display a `Post` object, or not.

Comment: My mistake. I guess what I'm looking for is a method that will return the `:controller` and `:id` associated with a given route. From there I can do something like `:controller.classify.constantize.find(:id)`